# Derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation using an infinite sum

Tags: solution-verification, alternative-proof, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider the functional

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
S[y] = \int_a^bF(y, y', x)\ dx.
\end{equation}

where $y(a) = A$ and $y(b) = B$. The Euler-Lagrange equation for finding the function $y(x)$ that makes the functional stationary is

$$\tag{2}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \right) = 0.
$$

I was curious to find whether we can deduce the Euler-Lagrange equation by writing y as an infinite sum, $y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$ and then differentiating $S$ with respect to the parameters $a_k$. However, I'm having some trouble with this deduction.

My attempt has given me

$$\tag{3}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial a_k}  =  \int_a^b \frac{\partial F(y, y', x)}{\partial a_k} \ dx = \int_a^b \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial a_k} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \frac{\partial y'}{\partial a_k} = 0,
$$

for all $k \geq 0$. Using the infinite sum, we find that

$$\tag{4}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial a_k} = x^k.
$$

And

$$\tag{5}
y'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k  k x^{k-1} \rightarrow \frac{\partial y'}{\partial a_k} = k x^{k-1}
$$

for $k  \gt 0$. For $k = 0$, $\frac{\partial y'}{\partial a_0} = 0$.

This gives the set of equations

$$\tag{6}
\int_a^b \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} dx = 0,
$$

for $k=0$ and, for $k > 0$,

$$\tag{7}
\int_a^b \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} x^k + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} k x^{k-1} \right)dx = 0.
$$

I have then attempted to use the integration by parts trick on the second term of the left-hand side, which gives

$$\tag{8}
\int_a^b \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} k x^{k-1} dx = \left [\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} x^{k} \right]_a^b - \int_a^b \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \right] x^k dx .
$$

Therefore,

$$\tag{9}
\int_a^b \left(  \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} x^k - \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \right] x^k \right) dx  = -\left [\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} x^{k} \right]_a^b
$$

From this point on I don’t know how to proceed.

Ideally, we would have

$$\tag{10}
-\left [\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} x^{k} \right]_a^b = 0
$$

so that we could write

$$\tag{11}
\int_a^b \left(  \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} x^k - \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \right] x^k \right) dx = \int_a^b \left(  \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \right] \right) x^k dx = 0, 
$$

which would maybe imply that it must be true that

$$\tag{12}
\left(  \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \right] \right) = 0,
$$

the Euler-Lagrange equation.
So, how can I proceed with the derivation? Is this derivation valid? (I'm not very worried about mathematical rigour).
Thanks

Comment: One problem with OP's derivation is that 2 of the $a_k$ modes are not independent because of the Dirichlet boundary conditions $y(a)=A$ and $y(b)=B.$ Alternatively we can make them independent by introducing [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)
$\tilde{S}~=~S+ \lambda(y(a)-A)+ \mu(y(b)-B).$

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks. I'm trying again using the Lagrange multipliers but haven't found an answer yet